# Cascading dropdown

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

Is there any alternative to json data to cascade dropdowns?
I am using country and state dropdown but cascading the data with json take too much time

```
 [HttpGet]
 public ActionResult States(int countryId)
 {
     DateTangoEntities _db = new DateTangoEntities();
     var tset = _db.States.Where(r => r.CountryID == countryId).Select(r =>
         new { r.StateName, r.StateID });
     return Json(tset, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
```

and here is the jquery part

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var countries = $("#Country");
    var regions = $("#States");

    countries.change(function () {
        regions.find('option').remove();
        $.getJSON('/Profile/States', { countryId: countries.val() }, function (data) {
            $(data).each(function () {
                $('#States').append('<option value="' + this.StateID + '">' + this.StateName + '</option>').resetSS();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I feel that you are missing the good old classic WebForms days :-)

Comment: what to do? any alternative to JSON?

Comment: You could probably show your code so that we could discuss about why it *takes too much time* (whatever this means) and suggest you ways to improve it.

Comment: My problem is that whenever i choose UK all the states in UK are filled and it takes around 10 to 15 secs to fill

Comment: You should try to pinpoint where are those 10-15sec wasted. Is it in the database? A network latency? Is it the browser trying to update many elements in the DOM?

Comment: i don't know but when i choose "Canada" it works fine because it does not have as many states in database as UK......But it kinda stops when i choose UK